# Set XmlEncoding to Dom Document in Java

Tags: dom, domdocument, xml-encoding

I need set the XmlEncoding (UTF-8) in a Dom Document object without use a Transformer with his "setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8")" method.

I don't want obtain the XML string using the Transform object because I am using a Xades XMLSignature library which uses a Document object to sign.

The problem is that for a Dom Document created as follow, his getXmlEncoding() method returns null.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();     
Document document = builder.newDocument();
document.getXmlEncoding();  //Returns null
```

But after apply the following code, the XmlEncoding methoth of the new DOM Document returns UTF-8 (requeriment for my xades library).
It's because the transformation process has added the encoding somehow.
For performance reasons I want to avoid to execute this code.

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");        

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);

String xml = writer.toString(); 
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();    
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);            
Document newDocument = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);

newDocument.getXmlEncoding(); //returns "UTF-8"
```

How I can create the Dom Document with the prolog information?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Apache Axiom's DOM implementation](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/implementations/axiom-dom/index.html). It implements both the DOM API and Axiom's own API, which actually allows setting the XML encoding. Simply add `axiom-dom` to your project and use the following instruction to get a `DocumentBuilderFactory`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = ((DOMMetaFactory)OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.FEATURE_DOM)).newDocumentBuilderFactory();
```

You can then set the XML encoding on a document as follows:

```
((OMDocument)document).setXMLEncoding("utf-8");
```

The rest of your code remains unchanged and can continue using the DOM API.